# Migrating to OpenJDK 11, which version of MySql connector is compatible for java 11?

Tags: java, mysql, java-11

I am trying to migrate my application from Java 8 to OpenJDK 11. I used MySql connector version 5 and its working fine. **Is it required to upgrade MySql connector JAR to version 8.0?**
I read about it from below link but they do not mentioned about Java 11.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-versions-java.html

Comment: The Connector/J docs don't seem to say anything about JDK 9 or newer. I recently had to demo something with Connector/J 8.0.11 on JDK 11 and JDK 12 builds and didn't run into any issues.

Comment: In my JDK11 migration, I had strange issues with Hibernate+Spring JPA with Connector/J 8.0, so rolled back to 5.1 for now.

Answer (score 3):

According to your reference, and [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-versions.html), we clearly can see that, MySQL connector version 5 uses `JDBC` version `3.0, 4.0, 4.1, 4.2`.

MySQL connector version 8 uses `JDB` version `4.2`.

Although `JDBC` version `4.2` supports JDK version 1.8.x, the new (for today) `JDBC` version 4.3 [supports](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/package-summary.html) `JDK` version `9`.

So, we wait new version of the `JDBC`, which supports `JDK 11`, then wait until MySQL supports new version of `JDBC` driver.

Comment: It's true they'd need to wait for a new (post 8.0, as yet unavailable) version of the connector to access featrues added in JDBC 4.3/Java 9, but the original question was about porting from Java 8 so wouldn't be using such APIs (at least not yet). See footnote 1 "Connector/J 8.0 implements JDBC 4.2. While Connector/J 8.0 works with libraries of higher JDBC versions, it returns a SQLFeatureNotSupportedException for any calls of methods supported only by JDBC 4.3 and higher". So they do seem to be claiming support for newer JREs provided they don't use new JDBC4.3+ features

Comment: This is all back to front. It is the JDK that supports the JDBC version, not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

I tested a sample mysql API to read a table. The configuration details are as below:

```
mysql-connector-java : version 8.0.21
java : openjdk version "11.0.8"
```

It was working fine.